# Большее из 3-х чисел

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Буквально пару дней разбираюсь  с bash и выдает 2 ошибки в строках 8 и 12.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter 1-st number"
read a
echo "Enter 2-nd number"
read b
echo "Enter 3-d number"
read c
if [["$a" > "$b"]] && [["$b" > "$c"]]
then
echo "$a the most biggest"
else
if [["$c">"$a"]] && [["$a" > "$b"]]
then
echo "$c the most biggest"
else
echo "$b the most biggest"
fi
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте двойные круглые скобки `((...))`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter 1-st number"
read a
echo "Enter 2-nd number"
read b
echo "Enter 3-d number"
read c
if (("$a" > "$b")) && (("$b" > "$c"))
then
echo "$a the most biggest"
else
if (("$c">"$a")) && (("$a" > "$b"))
then
echo "$c the most biggest"
else
echo "$b the most biggest"
fi
fi
```

Но у вас нарушена логика поиска большего числа. Так работает лучше:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter 1-st number"
read a
echo "Enter 2-nd number"
read b
echo "Enter 3-d number"
read c
# if (("$a" > "$b")) && (("$b" > "$c"))
if (("$a" > "$b")) && (("$a" > "$c"))
then
echo "$a the most biggest"
else
# if (("$c">"$a")) && (("$a" > "$b"))
if (("$с" > "$a")) && (("$c" > "$b"))
then
echo "$c the most biggest"
else
echo "$b the most biggest"
fi
fi
```

**Дополнение**

Можно использовать двойные квадратные скобки `[[...]]`, но внутри конструкции `[[ "$a" > "$b" ]]` они должны быть отделены пробелами.

Comment: теперь понял,спасибо

Comment: И этот весь геморрой, чтобы не использовать bc?